# Do the isomorphism classes of indecomposable objects in $R{\text{-mod}}$ form a set?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, set-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, abelian-categories

Let $R$ be a unital (associative) ring.  Consider the category $R\text{-mod}$ of unitary left $R$-modules.  Set $\text{Indec}(R)$ to be the class of all isomorphism classes of indecomposable objects in $R\text{-mod}$.

> Is $\text{Indec}(R)$ a set?  If not, for which ring $R$ is $\text{Indec}(R)$ a set, and for which ring $R$ is $\text{Indec}(R)$ a proper class?

Clearly, if $R$ is semisimple, then $\text{Indec}(R)$ coincides with the set $\text{Irred}(R)$ of isomorphism classes of simple $R$-modules.   I am not sure what would happen if $R$ is nonsemisimple.

If possible, I would like to request a reference that discusses a more general result.  That is, if $\mathscr{C}$ is an arbitrary abelian category, and $\text{Indec}(\mathscr{C})$ is the class of all isomorphism classes of indecomposable objects in $\mathscr{C}$.  How do we tell when $\text{Indec}(\mathscr{C})$ is a set?

Just as in the case of $R\text{-mod}$, the same observation holds: if $\mathscr{C}$ is semisimple, then $\text{Indec}(\mathscr{C})$ is identical to the class $\text{Irred}(\mathscr{C})$ of isomorphism classes of simple objects in $\mathscr{C}$.  <s>However, I am very certain that there are nonsemisimple abelian category $\mathscr{C}$ such that $\text{Indec}(\mathscr{C})$ is a proper class.  Such an example is very welcome.</s>  $\phantom{aaa}$ *Edit:*  With [help from YCor](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/369834/do-the-isomorphism-classes-of-indecomposable-objects-in-r-text-mod-form-a#comment933965_369834), at least when $R=\mathbb{Z}$, $\text{Indec}(\mathbb{Z})$ is a proper class.

**Remark.**  I am even more interested in the case where $R$ is a (not necessarily finite-dimensional) $\mathbb{K}$-algebra for some field $\mathbb{K}$.  We may assume that $R$ is countable-dimesional.  Even more specifically, I would like to know what happens if $R$ is the universal enveloping algebra of some (not necessarily finite-dimensional) Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ over some field $\mathbb{K}$.  Again, we may assume that $\mathfrak{g}$ is countable-dimensional.  However, anything that can elaborate me on how to find out when $\text{Indec}(\mathscr{C})$ is a set will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the question is equivalent to: does there exist an upper bound $\alpha=\alpha_R$ on the cardinals of indecomposable $R$-modules.

Comment: For $R=\mathbf{Z}$ the answer is no, and there seems to be a lot of literature on the subject. It seems to also be no for the $p$-adic ring $\mathbf{Z}_p$, as examples of arbitrary large abelian groups (the easiest apparently) can be chosen as abelian $p$-groups.

Comment: @YCor  Could you please provide a reference for the case $R=\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: I searched [indecomposable abelian groups large cardinal] and immediately got references.

Comment: @YCor  Thank you.   That settled one of my questions.

Answer (score 12):

In Conjecture $1_{\infty}$ of

*Simson, Daniel*, On large indecomposable modules, endo-wild representation type and right pure semisimple rings., Algebra Discrete Math. 2003, No. 2, 93-118 (2003). [ZBL1067.16029](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1067.16029),

Simson conjectures that a right noetherian ring either

- is right pure semisimple (which would imply it is right artinian, and conjecturally would imply that it is right artinian of finite representation type), or
- has indecomposable modules of arbitrarily large cardinality.

So if this conjecture is true, then the answer to the question "for which *noetherian* rings is $\operatorname{Indec}(R)$ a proper class" is "almost all of them".

Simson proved this conjecture for several classes of finite dimensional algebras (e.g., finite dimensional local $k$-algebras with residue field $k$, and group algebras of finite groups) in

*Simson, Daniel*, [**On Corner type endo-wild algebras.**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jpaa.2005.01.012), J. Pure Appl. Algebra 202, No. 1-3, 118-132 (2005). [ZBL1151.16014](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1151.16014).

For non-noetherian rings the answer will be more complicated, since, for example, there are non-noetherian rings for which every indecomposable module is simple.